# How can we easily remove an element from an multi dimensional array object in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, arrayobject

I am working in react Js. There is a trouble for me to remove an item corresponding to "product_option_value_id" .I need to remove item from product_option_value ( child array object) if my given itemId==product_option_value_id, and return whole array object after removing the specified item. I think the idea is clear . I tried a method , but I got undefined.

```
        "default": 0,
        "master_option": 0,
        " master_option_value": 0,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "Choose Size",
        "option_id": "4",
        "product_option_id": "111",
        "product_option_value": [{
                "ec_product_id": "",
                "exclude_others": "0",
                "image": "",
                "master_option_value": "0",
                "name": "25ml",
                "option_value_id": "8",
                "points": "0",
                "product_option_value_id": "267"
            },
            {
                " ec_product_id": "22w",
                "exclude_others": "0",
                "image": "",
                "master_option_value": "0",
                "name": "25ml",
                "option_value_id": "8",
                "points": "0",
                "product_option_value_id": "266"
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "default": 0,
        "master_option": 0,
        " master_option_value": 0,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "Water",
        "option_id": "4",
        "product_option_id": "111",
        "product_option_value": [{
                "ec_product_id": "",
                "exclude_others": "0",
                "image": "",
                "master_option_value": "0",
                "name": "25ml",
                "option_value_id": "8",
                "points": "0",
                "product_option_value_id": "700"
            },
            {
                " ec_product_id": "22w",
                "exclude_others": "0",
                "image": "",
                "master_option_value": "0",
                "name": "50ml",
                "option_value_id": "8",
                "points": "0",
                "product_option_value_id": "701"
            },
            {
                " ec_product_id": "22w",
                "exclude_others": "0",
                "image": "",
                "master_option_value": "0",
                "name": "500ml",
                "option_value_id": "8",
                "points": "0",
                "product_option_value_id": "702"
            }, {
                " ec_product_id": "22w",
                "exclude_others": "0",
                "image": "",
                "master_option_value": "0",
                "name": "500ml",
                "option_value_id": "8",
                "points": "0",
                "product_option_value_id": "703"
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

The method I tried

```
 const removeOption=(itemId:any)=>{
                const filteredItems =  productOptions.forEach(function(o:any) {
            o.product_option_value = o.product_option_value.filter((s:any) => s.product_option_value_id != itemId);
          });
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `forEach` method does not return the array, that is why you are getting `undefined` as result. This method just perform a function for each element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

So you need to use the `.map()` method instead:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

so basically:

```
const removeOption = (itemId: any) => {
    return productOptions.map((o: any) => {
        return { ...o, product_option_value: o.product_option_value.filter((s: any) => s.product_option_value_id !== itemId)};
    });
}
```